# Logic condition between three or more elements in python

Tags: python, logic, logical-operators

I would like to return a panda boolean series based on the following logic sentence:

if my My_Panda_series is different of 100 or 0 return true if it is equal to 100 or 1 return false.

For instance with if an element of my panda series is equal to 90 it would return true, if an element of my panda series is equal to 0 it would return false

Of course one could simply use numpy logic operations as:

```
logical_not(numpy.logical_or(my_panda_series==100,my_panda_series==0))
```

But I would like something more concise and scalable. For instance, I would like a function that returns true whenever the element of my cell belongs to the list/numpy.array [0,100]. In this way, if I increase the number of elements for which the logic function must return false, I don't have to write entire new logic conditions.

I am sure Python offers something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method:

```
my_panda_series.isin(my_numpy_array)
```